# Why is INT_MIN defined in the header file limits.h of the c language (-INT_MAX-1) instead of directly using -2147483648

Tags: c

```
#define INT_MAX 2147483647
#define INT_MIN (-INT_MAX-1)
```

When I was reading the book csapp, I found that the author raised this question, but I didn't understand why it should be defined in this way. What is the difference between directly using `-2147483647` to define it?

Comment: @anatolyg No, why would it?

Comment: @user207421 It is directly answered in the comment by Lundin to that question. In any case, I agree that people searching for an answer to this question will not find that question unless they already know the answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we have a better duplicate somewhere. I mean we shouldn't close something as dupe because a _comment_ happened to answer the question. I'll see if I can find one...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%d, %zu\n",-2147483647-1,  sizeof(-2147483647-1)); 
    printf("%d, %zu\n",(int)-2147483648, sizeof(-2147483648)); 
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
-2147483648, 4
-2147483648, 8
```

The standard says:

> An integer constant begins with a digit, but has no period or exponent part. It may have a prefix that specifies its base and a suffix that specifies its type.

Note that the `-` is not part of the constant. It is a negation operator that is applied after the constant is interpreted.

So for `-2147483648`, the compiler will use the `2147483648` part to determine its type. For that, the standard says:

> The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can
> be represented.
> [image]

Since there is no suffix that specifies its type, and `2147483648` can't be represented by int (as INT_MAX is `2147483647`), its type will be `long int`, then `sizeof INT_MIN` will be 8, which is wrong.

Comment: This quotation from the Standard doesn't actually say *why* `-2147483648` is taken as a `long`.

Comment: @user207421 yes, i have edited the answer to explain that

Comment: *its type will be `long int`*: its type will be `long int` or `long long int` depending on the range of type `long int`.

Comment: You might also mention that `0x80000000` is not a solution because it has type `unsigned int` and neither is `((int)-2147483648)` because it cannot be used in a preprocessor expression.