# Writing the smallest (signed) 32-bit number as a C++ literal

Tags: c++, literals

If I wished to use the <limits> header, it would be easy to write the smallest integer:

```
std::int32_t small = std::numeric_limits<std::int32_t>::min();
```

This makes `small` equal to -2147483648.

I'm working in a library where such numbers are spelled out.  Thus it would be preferred to write

```
std::int32_t small = -2147483648;
```

I'm having trouble with this on Visual Studio, but when I read the C++ spec, I find it suggests that I can't do this for any compiler.  The reason I think I can't do this is that the spec indicates that a integer-literal does not include the negative sign.  The negative sign actually becomes a unary-minus later.  So C++ processes the integer literal 2147483648.  This number is too large to fit in an int (assuming int is 32-bits, which it is on the platform I'm considering), so it must be a long int (64-bits).

(Incidentally, this is where I run awry on visual studio.  It appears to treat 2147483648 as an unsigned long, rather than a signed long, but this question is about the spec behavior)

From what I can see, there's no way to write the 32 bit number -2147483648 as a 32-bit literal.  You have to make it a 64-bit literal first, 2147483648UL, then negate it.  This seems like an oversight, but it also seems to compile everywhere (except Visual Studio), so what did I miss?

Comment: You are correct about `-2147483648` being a larger integer type that gets negated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45469214/why-does-the-most-negative-int-value-cause-an-error-about-ambiguous-function-ove/45469321#45469321

Comment: I wouldn't describe -2147483648 as 'small'. That suggests 1 or zero. It is the *minimum.* Not the same thing.

Comment: @user207421 But on the scale of real numbers, -2147483648 is indeed smaller than 0 let alone 1.

Comment: There are actually no negative integral literals.   I'd suggest a documented exemption in this case for the rule that "such numbers are spelled out", and simply use `std::numeric_limits<std::int32_t>::min()`.   Possibly with a comment indicating that.

Comment: Bending yourself backwards just so you can hardcode constants sounds ill-advised.

Comment: I think the library has the problem backward... it is time your library embraces the C++ standard more. `std::numeric_limits<std::int32_t>::min();` really communicates intent (!) much better than some "magic number" and less surprising to most C++ developers. Also you should not have to worry about this value changing anytime so you don't need to protect against that

Comment: [Why is `INT_MIN` defined in the header file limits.h `-INT_MAX-1` instead of directly using `-2147483648`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77034878/995714). In other words its impossible to write it in a single or 2 tokens. I don't know why it must be spelled out like that? That rule will [cause issues again with `std::numeric_limits<std::int64_t>::min()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61290562/995714) if you don't allow exceptions for 64-bit ints

Comment: I guess C++20 has made it easier; however it might look counter-intuitive: `auto constexpr min32s = std::bit_cast<std::int32_t>(1ul << 31ul);` the bit pattern is valid in both input and output types, but with different meanings.

Comment: There are no negative literals in C++. So the answers are proposing expressions that are not literals. So you need to clarify the question: What kinds of expressions are acceptable? Why is some compound expression involving subtraction or bit manipulation better than use of the standard-defined expression for the minimum value?

Answer (score 2):

Trivial solution is to bitwise invert the *maximum* value of the proper type. Given all the fixed width types are guaranteed to use two's complement representation, bitwise invert of the largest maximum value will always produce the most negative value (negation is the same as flipping all the bits and adding one; invert omits the adding one step, so you end up with a negative number one further from zero), so you can reliably do:

```
std::int32_t small = ~INT32_C(2147483647);
```

The `INT32_C` is function macro to make an integer constant of the correct size (it'll usually expand to nothing, making it `~2147483647`, unless `int` on your system is not the same size as `int32_t`).

Answer (score 1):

-2147483648 has two parts: the integer literal 2147483648 and the `-` sign which negates it. 2147483648 is too large to fit in a 32-bit `int` type, so the compiler treats it as a larger type. Negating it doesn't change the type, and the result of the negation still won't fit in an `int`.

The most straightforward approach is to ensure that you're dealing with an `int`:

```
int min_val = -2147483647 - 1;
```

This approach has the advantage of working for any twos-complement type. `-MAX_VAL` has the same type as `MAX_VAL`, and subtracting 1 gives you the minimum value.

Answer (score 0):

An integer literal too big for an int gets interpreted as a larger type, even if you don't put an `L` on the literal. On platforms with 64-bit `long`, `std::int32_t small = -2147483648;` is treated as negating a long, then converting it to `std::int32_t` for the assignment. Neither an explicit `L` nor an explicit cast to `std::int32_t` is required.

On platforms with 32-bit `long`, `2147483648` doesn't fit in a long. As of C++11, it would be interpreted as a long long, but older standards leave the behavior undefined. Interpreting too-big literals as unsigned long was common before C++11, especially since older C standards mandated unsigned long. Your Visual Studio settings seem to be set to an older standard.